# Generation query when the ManyToMany relationship is used by Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

How to write sql query in jpa query.....

```
select s.skill_name from K_ACTIVITI_POC.review r,  K_ACTIVITI_POC.task t ,K_ACTIVITI_POC.task_skill ts,  K_ACTIVITI_POC.skills s 
where r.rev_id = t.rev_id 
and t.task_id = ts.task_id
and s.skill_id= ts.skill_id
and r.rev_id =1
and t.task_id=1;
```

below have java code..........

```
public interface SkillRepository extends CrudRepository<Skill, Long> {

    @Query("select s.skill_name from Review r Skill s INNER JOIN USER_SKILL ON s.skillId=sb.skillId INNER JOIN Task t ON t.taskId=sb.taskId where r.revId =:revId and t.task_id=:taskId;")
    public List<Skill> findByAllSkills(@Param("revId") Long revId, @Param("taskId")Long taskId);

}
```

Comment: thats a single column projection.. change return type to List<String>

Comment: Do you just want the skill name? Then you could do List<String> or List<SkillName> where SkillName just contains the skillname, and your query would be select new SkillName(s.skill_name) ...

Comment: yes... i just want skill name